# Visual Basic. Method cannot be reflected

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-7, .net-4.5

I have a problem using soap client in vb.net with Visual Studio 2015 Community. I want to use to soap client library, but I can't find it.

So, I found the `wsdl.exe` command in Visual Studio 2015 Community. I tried wsdl.exe. It generated the code in the following link:

https://github.com/yahoojp-marketing/sponsored-search-api-documents/blob/master/wsdl/LocationService.wsdl

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>wsdl /l:VB https://ss.yahooapis.jp/services/V6.0/LocationService?wsdl /out:C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\
```

I added the Project and successfully compiled it. However, an exception occurs when instantiate the object in this line.

```
Dim LocationServiceWsdl As New LocationService()
```

Below is the error message.

> Message: LocationService.get cannot to be reflected
>   
> InnnerException: An error occurred while reflecting the SoapHeader.
>   
> at:
>   
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs)
>   
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType.GenerateXmlMappings(Type type, ArrayList soapMethodList, String serviceNamespace, Boolean serviceDefaultIsEncoded, ArrayList mappings)
>   
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
>   
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()

## LocationService.vb

```
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("RequestHeader"),
 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("ResponseHeader", Direction:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.Out),
 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace:="http://ss.yahooapis.jp/V6", ResponseNamespace:="http://ss.yahooapis.jp/V6", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)>
Public Function [get](ByVal accountId As Long, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("error")> ByRef [error]() As [Error]) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("rval")> LocationReturnValue
    Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("get", New Object() {accountId}) ' <- maybe error occurs here.
    [error] = CType(results(1), [Error]())
    Return CType(results(0), LocationReturnValue)
End Function
```

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the innerexception you can see the actual error is related to the SoapHeader class generated by wsdl.exe.

```
Types 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader' and 'FullNamespaceToYourClass.SoapHeader' both use the XML type name, 'SoapHeader', from namespace 'http://ss.yahooapis.jp/V6'. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.
```

You could either rename the SoapHeader class within the LocationService.vb file to something else or alternately add the full namespace to your class within the XmlTypeAttribute:

```
'''<remarks/>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.6.1055.0"),
System.SerializableAttribute(),
System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName:="FullNamespaceToYourClass.SoapHeader", [Namespace]:="http://ss.yahooapis.jp/V6"),
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("RequestHeader", [Namespace]:="http://ss.yahooapis.jp/V6", IsNullable:=False)>

Partial Public Class SoapHeader
    Inherits System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
```